# Пересечение view

Tags: android, customview

Недавно были опубликованы исходники приложения Kickstarter. Там есть один интересный элемент:[image: введите сюда описание изображения] В первом `item` у `recyclerview` `cardview` пересекается с другой `view`. В исходники еще не заглядывал, поэтому вопрос: как такое реализовать? Конечно есть вариант что нужно это все обернуть в layout. Но может есть какие-нибудь красивые варианты, как например с anchor в `CoordinatorLayout`?

Comment: ну я бы просто положил карточку во framelayout с паддингом сверху небольшим. когда надо (если эта табличка динамически добавляется), эту табличку с сердечком кидал во фреймлэйаут. Не вижу тут потребности в какой то особой изощренной сложности и красивом варианте, чем проще тем лучше

Answer (score 0):

Тут только 2 варианта -

1. Обернуть карточку в другой контейнер и помещать всё остальное поверх карточки
2. Играться с отрицательными `margin` - но это чревато ворохом проблем - не надо так.

Comment: Ну вот я тоже первого варианта по предерживаюсь